# How Can I extract the Data that I Want In a Callback Function From a YQL Query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, yql

I have managed to return a callback function containing the titles related to a submitted string that is entered into a text input box, but I am not sure how I can now extract just the titles from the callback function that is returned when I enter and submit a search term.

**Here is the JSFiddle of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/JAS4H/39/**

If you enter a search term and press the Search! button beneath the text input box you can see the cbfunc that is returned by the YQL query.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
function cbfunc(data) {
    var s = ''; 

    $.each(data.query.results.result, function(i, item) {
        s += '<p>' + item.title + '</p>';
    });    
    $('#searchResults').html(s);
}


$(function() {

    $('#search').live('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + 
                encodeURIComponent('SELECT title FROM search.web WHERE query="' +
                this.searchBar.value + '"') +
                '&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=cbfunc',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'callback',
            jsonpCallback: 'cbfunc'
        });
    });

});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/JAS4H/59/